# powershell checking boolean environment variable

Tags: powershell

I ran into something strange, and I don't understand what is happening:

```
PS C:\> $env:x = $false
PS C:\> if($env:x){'what'}
what
PS C:\> $env:x
False
```

So the value is actually false, but what does the `if` check? Clearly not the value of `x`. What is happening?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Environment` provider (which implements the `env:` drive) only supports *string* items, and will coerce any assigned value to a `[string]`:

```
PS C:\> $env:x = $false
PS C:\> $env:x.GetType()

IsPublic IsSerial Name                                     BaseType
-------- -------- ----                                     --------
True     True     String                                   System.Object
```

... and the default `[string]`-to-`[bool]` conversion rules in PowerShell holds that *non-empty strings* are converted to `$true`:

```
PS C:\> $true -eq 'false'
True
PS C:\> [bool]'false'
True
PS C:\> [bool]''
False
```

---

To *parse* a string value (like `"false"`) to its equivalent `[bool]` value, you need to either call [`[bool]::Parse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.parse):

```
if([bool]::Parse($env:x)){
    'what'
}
```

... or, if the string value might not be a valid truthy/falsy value, use [`[bool]::TryParse()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.boolean.tryparse):

```
$env:x = $false
$result = $false
if([bool]::TryParse($env:x, [ref]$result) -and $result){
  'what'
}
```